TypeScript error: Type parameter 'T' has a circular constraint
type FuncHasArgumentsCheck<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = 
    T extends (...args: []) => any
        ? never // zero arguments
        : T;

// Extracts the first argument type, or `never` if no arguments are found.
type FuncFirstArgumentType<T extends FuncHasArgumentsCheck<T>> = 
    T extends (first: infer TFirst, ...args: any[]) => any
        ? TFirst 
        : never;

TypeScript shows error in this code:

Type parameter 'T' has a circular constraint.(2313)

Why can't it resolve this seemingly simple type check constraint and where exactly the "circularity" is?
FuncHasArgumentsCheck doesn't depend on FuncFirstArgumentType so I can't see what it finds 'circular' here.

It because you have T extending itself in FuncFirstArgumentType. You want it to instead be:
type FuncFirstArgumentType<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown> =
  T extends (first: infer TFirst, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown
    ? TFirst
    : never;

But if no arguments are defined, your type will be unknown instead of never. Therefore, you can amend the above code to include another extends check on the inferred type.
type FuncFirstArgumentType<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown> =
  T extends (first: infer TFirst, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown
    ? TFirst extends unknown
      ? never
      : TFirst
    : never;

This will get you the type of your first argument in the given function and incases where there are no arguments, it will return never. In addition, you no longer need the original FuncHasArgumentsCheck.
However, I think you're trying to over complicate everything. TypeScript provides a bunch of utility types for purposes like this. For your FuncHasArgumentsCheck type, you can instead use TypeScripts Parameters type utility which returns an array of parameter types. i.e.,
function tempFunc(a: number, b: string) {}
type FuncArgs = Parameters<typeof tempFunc>;
// FuncArgs = [number, string]

You can then index FuncArgs to get the parameter type you want. Of course, this does not work if tempFunc has no parameters as FuncArgs will be empty and will throw a type error if you try and index it. To solve this, you can use the following generic type:
type FirstParam<T extends unknown[]> = T[0] extends never ? never : T[0];

This takes in the list of param types (i.e, FuncArgs) and returns the type of the first argument if it exists, Else, it returns undefined.
Hope this helps!

I'm learning TypeScript, so I'm trying to write types myself some of which have already been implemented. In this case, I wanted to restrict the type of the input parameter to a function with some arguments (so that the compiler would error when trying to use FuncFirstArgumentType<T> with a function type without arguments), but it seems to be impossible. BTW, why do you prefer unknown to any in this case?

@Serg FuncHasArgumentsCheck needs to be something more like this: type FuncWithArgs<T> = T extends (...args: []) => unknown ? never : T;. You can then create a generic function which accepts a type T that extends from type Function: function temp<T extends Function>(cb: FuncWithArgs<T>). When you now use this temp function and try and pass in a function with no argument will get a type error. You mistake lies in how you use extends. In <> its a constraint, but outside, its more like an if statement; the ternary operator and never become the constraint

@Serg Type any and unknown are very similar. However, whilst any allows me to do anything to it, unknown only allows me to do something once I've narrowed its type. i.e., I cant call a value of type unknown until I've narrowed its type to Function. This article explains it better. All in all, it good practice to use unknown instead of any
